# how solve ERROR: Cannot start IntelliJ IDEA on arch while run idea.sh?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

while i run idea.sh on terminal i get this error :

```
/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 24: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 25: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 27: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 28: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 29: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 30: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 31: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 32: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 33: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 34: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 11: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 13: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 15: which: command not found

/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh: line 17: which: command not found

ERROR: Cannot start IntelliJ IDEA
Required tools are missing - check beginning of "/home/esmael/Downloads/Compressed/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh" file for details.
```

My system is arch but i have install recently and I had already fixed it on both Fedora and Arch and I did not have this problem

Comment: this screenshot for my problem : 
https://ibb.co/tpZvFB1

Comment: Looks like the 'which' command is not installed on your system. Try installing it and try again.

Comment: mwarren  I am a campaign from the official website and according to what the official website says only must open the idea.sh to open the program and actually this is what happened before me but I do not know why the problem now

Comment: Have you tried typing which on the command line? Does it say command not found?

Comment: no i just try run idea.sh

Comment: Running idea.sh does not guarantee it has everything it needs to complete. It is reasonably clear that your setup does not have everything set up that is required.

Comment: So what's the way to solve such a problem?

Comment: Install the which command.

Comment: @mwarren which is a shell builtin, not something one can install. If it really doesn't work (which it does look like), that must mean that `/bin/sh` points to some unconventional shell.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you have the same problem that can be solved like i solved it, bu I'm gonna tell you either way so maybe you can find a solution for your case.
For me when I downloaded the tar.gz file it got stored in in the tmp and at first I extracted it there and ran the idea.sh from there. But when I moved it in another directory it gave me the same error it gave you except for the witch thing. So I just put it back in tmp and it works, idk why but hope it helps.